# Returning nearest rows key up or down

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to get the item_id returned of the row closest above or closest below. For example:

[image]

So if I want the the row below, I would input 3 and 1 would get returned. If I wanted above 3 would be inputted and 4 would get returned.

something like: `exec [myFunction] 3, 'up';`

I was looking into getting the closest relative number (https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/73804/how-to-retrieve-closest-value-based-on-look-up-table). But the problem is that it will return the closest number. If I inputted 3 but the next number up was 7 adding one to make 4 and running this would result in 3 again. I hope that makes sense.

Then I looked it using the ABS function(http://www.techfounder.net/2009/02/02/selecting-closest-values-in-mysql/).

```
    SELECT top 1 item_id, ABS(3) AS distance
FROM ndc
ORDER BY distance
```

It has a similar problem.

How do I achieve the desired results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if @direction = 'up'
    begin
        select top(1) item_id from table_name
        where item_id > @inputNumber
        order by item_id asc
    end
else 
    begin
        select top(1) item_id from table_name
        where item_id < @inputNumber
        order by item_id desc
    end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can incorporate this into a single query:

```
select top 1 item_id
from ncd
where (item_id < @item_id and @dir = 'down') or
      (item_id > item_id and @dir = 'up')
order by (case when @dir = 'up' then item_id end) asc,
         (case when @dir = 'down' then item_id end) desc;
```

But I advise you to use two queries:

```
select top 1 item_id
from ncd
where item_id > @item_id
order by item_id end asc;

select top 1 item_id
from ncd
where item_id < @item_id
order by item_id end desc;
```

Then use `if` logic in the stored procedure.  These can more readily take advantage of an index on `ncd(item_id)`.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you just set a parameter called @UpOrDown and in the where clause, put

```
case when @UpOrDown = 'Above' then ITEM_ID > 3 else ITEM_ID < 3 end
```